# Autocomplete field not working

Tags: ajax

I am making a form with autocomplete fields and I am not able to make it work (using an example code from a tutorial). The strange thing is that when I test it in my local drupal installation (bitnami drupal stack 7.38 on my PC) it works, but the same module on a server instance (it's 7.38, too) doesn't work (the json file with matches is created correctly but there are no matches displayed when I type something in the form field). Does anybody know what might be a cause?

Comment: check the error log, may be you might have some errors with json objects.

Comment: you mean log messages? there are no reported errors on this subject

Comment: check the error or the response for the autocomplete fields in the firebug...